# Server generated hover image?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, liferay

I need to have hover button which depends on server side settings. I.e. when setting is A, images are A.png and Ahover.png, when setting is B, images are B.png and Bhover.png and so on. So, for each setting two (or more) images are defined.

Suppose I can neither generate CSS on server side nor can embed style directives in the content file.

Actually I am in a portlet. My portlet can have multiple instances. And each instance can have different setting (image).

The problem is that I need to define TWO images -- normal and hover.

1) If I define them in CSS they will not change in reflect on setting change (because CSS is not generated on server)

2) I can't define hover style inline (CSS limitation), so I can't define both images in HTML code

3) I don't know how to write `jQuery` code since there apparently is impossible to set pseudoclass styles with `jQuery`.

Below is sample code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<!-- available variables -->
<!-- contextPath = <c:out value="${contextPath}"/> -->
<!-- image.big.normal = <c:out value="${image.big.normal}"/> -->
<!-- image.big.hover = <c:out value="${image.big.hover}"/> -->

<div class="promotion-frame">

    <div class="promotion-icon jqueryeffect">
        By jQuery
    </div>

    <div class="promotion-icon" style="background-image: url('<c:out value="${contextPath}"/><c:out value="${image.big.normal}"/>')">
        By Inline Style
    </div>

    <!-- but how to set hover image??????? -->

    <div class="promotion-title">
        Communicator
    </div>

</div>

<liferay-util:html-bottom>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        var divId = 'p_p_id_<c:out value="${portletDisplay.id}"/>_';
        var backgroundImageStyle = "url('";
        backgroundImageStyle += '<c:out value="${contextPath}"/>';
        backgroundImageStyle += '<c:out value="${image.big.normal}"/>';
        backgroundImageStyle += "')";

        jQuery.noConflict();

        jQuery('#' + divId + ' ' + '.jqueryeffect').css('background-image', backgroundImageStyle);

        // but how to set hover image???

    </script>
</liferay-util:html-bottom>
```

Comment: are all of these images the same size ?

Answer (score 0):

If the images are all the same size, then you can combine the normal and hover images in one image (*one at the top and the bottom*) and use a CSS rule that is agnostic to the actual file..

So

```
.promotion-icon{
   /*define width and height that fits the icon*/
   background-position: left top; /*assuming that the normal state of the icon is at the top*/
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-color:tansparent;
}
.promotion-icon{
   background-position:left bottom;
}
```

Now this code will work

```
<div class="promotion-icon" style="background-image: url('<c:out value="${contextPath}"/><c:out value="${image.big.combined}"/>')">
    By Inline Style
</div>
```